# Rxjava as event bus

Tags: android, event-handling, rx-java, rx-android

I am trying to implement event processing in my app using Rxjava publishsubject.

Event bus will be shared between multiple activities, fragments and a service.

The service does my background processing work (runs every 30 secs).

Issues :

1. I would like that every event that has some flag set be saved in the DB. I would like to attach a generic listener for this. How can I achieve this? In which context should this run?
2. Service will read persisted events and process them if it deems necessary.

Comment: Hi Adimo, can you post some code to show what you tried so far? This is almost always a good idea.

Comment: Maybe you should consider existing libraries? RxRelay for a bus and [android-priority-jobqueue](https://github.com/yigit/android-priority-jobqueue).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually we implemented and RxBus. We backed it up with an eventstore on local db. Then we ran a service which queries database for new events which are then loaded onto the bus.

We were looking for some product that does this by default. Could not find one.